# Fill a "form" and "submit" using javascript automatically without pressing "submit"

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have looked at different threads but couldn't find a proper solution.
I want to make a fake html file which fills a form automatically and submits when it is loaded by the browser.

The two input fields `maks` and `reciever` are filled by the values I have given, but I need to press submit.
And if possible it could be nice if the values of the input fields are invisible. Thank you.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function postReq() {
        var frm = document.getElementById('post_req');
        if (frm) {
          frm.submit();
        }
      }
    </script>

  <body onload="postReq()">
    <form method=POST name=exampleform id='post_req'
       action="/ex/makfoer.php">
      <input name=maks type=hidden value="2" /> 
      <input name=reciever type=hidden value="otto" />
      <input type=submit />
    </form>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: You should close your `<head>` tag

Comment: The code you have is fine. What exactly is not working?

Comment: I have to press "submit" in order to make the event. But what i want is doing it automatically without pressing.

Answer (score 2):

In your case you could just use:

`document.exampleform.submit();`

**Explanation:**

`exampleform` is the name of your form, so you can get the form with:

`document.exampleform`

Now you only activate the `.submit()` method of the form. You don't need a submit button to submit. So everything is hidden.

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Close your `<head>` tag.

**2.** Use quotes for the values of attributes `name`, `type`, etc.

**3.** No need for a submit button, especially since you don't want your form to be visible

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function postReq() {
        var frm = document.getElementById('post_req');
        if (frm) {
          frm.submit();
        }
      }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body onload="postReq()">
    <form method="POST" name="exampleform" id='post_req'
       action="/ex/makfoer.php">
      <input name="maks" type="hidden" value="2" /> 
      <input name="reciever" type="hidden" value="otto" />
    </form>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: I want to see the submit button even though it is not making any sense, since the intention of this is a fake html of the original one only to make the user confusing and i want the inputs "maks"'s and "reciever"'s values to be hidden not the button itself.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to do that without jQuery, use [window.onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onload) event handler:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function postReq() {
    var frm = document.getElementById('post_req');
    if (frm) {
      frm.submit();
    }
  }
  window.onload = postReq;
</script>
</head>
```

`window.onload` is fired when the whole page is loaded (including external scripts, images, etc.), as opposed to `document.onload` which is fired once the DOM of the page is parsed and loaded.

Comment: it doesn't work and i want the input to be hidden not visible

Comment: Sorry I misread and saw 'visible' instead of invisible. Also as pointed out by abl you should close the head tag. Edited my answer.

Comment: yes i have but no difference :(

Comment: When I copy the code on on a file on my computer, it works. You have javascript activated, right? Do you get any error in the browser or in the console?

Comment: yes javascript is activated and i get no error.